# Tags for medical/health questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I've asked a few medical questions, those have been kindly retagged with [health](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) or [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine). Those terms certainly don't mean the same thing, but I think there is a significant grey area between them.

How should we tag those questions, any ideas on some general guidelines.

Comment: I think it's probably too early to worry about this. Let's wait until there are a few more questions, and see if we can come up with a clearer picture of how and when these tags should be used.

Answer (score 3):

I think that questions tagged with health should be retagged with medicine or nutrition, whichever of the two is most appropriate. Health is just too vague of a tag.

Answer (score 3):

What about a question like [this](http://www.treehugger.com/files/2010/02/are-standing-desks-healthier-than-sitting.php) which is related to health but not medicine or nutrition? Is there a more appropriate tag for this?

Comment: I'd tag that one ergonomics.