# Health-related tags

Tags: discussion

We have a number of different tags related to health, and I am wondering if we need some synonyms and a clean-up.

I propose that, on each line, the latter ones should be merged with the first.

- [health](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), [healing](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healing)
- [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine), [medical](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical), [evidence-based-medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence-based-medicine)
- [alternative-medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-medicine), [alt-medicines](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alt-medicines)
- [placebo](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placebo), [placebo-effect](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placebo-effect)
- [nutritional-supplements](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutritional-supplements), [supplements](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supplements)
- [pharmaceutical](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmaceutical), [drug-development](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drug-development)

We have many tags for particular conditions:

- [cancer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cancer), [breast-cancer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breast-cancer) - Not the same, but don't need both.
- [common-cold](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-cold), [cold](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold), [flu](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flu) - Not the same, but don't need both common-cold and flu.
- [hiv](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiv), [aids](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aids) - suggest replacing with a single HIV-AIDS tag.

Any suggestions or objections?

Comment: [tag:health] and [tag:healing] are already synonyms of [tag:medicine], [alt-medicines] is also a synonym already. I agree that all the others should be merged, I'm not sure for all of them which is the best name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Progress Report

### Was Already Done

- [health](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), [healing](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healing) -- Already linked to medicine
- [alternative-medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-medicine), [alt-medicines](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alt-medicines)
- [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine), [medical](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical),

### Now Done

- [pharmaceutical](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmaceutical), [drug-development](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drug-development)
- [placebo](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placebo), [placebo-effect](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placebo-effect)
- [hiv](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiv), [aids](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aids) - suggest replacing with a single HIV-AIDS tag.
- [common-cold](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-cold), [cold](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold)
- [nutritional-supplements](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutritional-supplements), [supplements](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supplements)
- [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine), [evidence-based-medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence-based-medicine)
- [cancer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cancer), [breast-cancer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breast-cancer) - Not the same, but don't need both.

### Decided not to do

- [common-cold](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-cold), [flu](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flu)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding alternative medicine - is there such thing? I would assume any question regarding "alternative" medicine could be handled as a medicine question.

Regarding [health](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) and [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine), see also [Tags for medical/health questions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/tags-for-medical-health-questions)

Comment: Suma, good find with that other question.  Let me return the favour: I was going to propose alternative medicine and medicine be merged, until I saw David Hedlund's answer [here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/85/do-we-need-an-alt-medicine-and-a-medicine-tag).

Answer (score 0):

I'm prompted to suggest that [alternative-medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-medicine) and [natural-remedies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-remedies) are, in practice, synonyms.

But I think both these are useful to keep separate from [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) and [medical-science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-science).

Comment: They are not the same: homeopathy is alternative medicine but not a natural remedy; home-made shampoos may be natural remedies but not alternative medicine. I am aware that they are synonyms on wikipedia, but...

Comment: ... but they are said to be **synonymous**!